# Extracting single jar inside zip using gradle task

Tags: gradle

I’m trying to extract a jar from a zip file which is available inside the zip as below structure.

```
test.zip /web-inf /lib /result1.jar
```

Here is the task:-

```
task unzip(type: Copy){ 
    group "testgroup"
    def zipFile = file("$buildDir/test.zip") 
    def tree = zipTree(zipFile) 
    from(tree.matching { include "**/result1.jar"}) 
    into "$builddir/dir"
    includeEmptyDirs = false 
}
```

But I am getting jar file with folder structure like `/web-inf/lib/result1.jar`. I want jar file alone, not the folders (`/web-inf/lib/`).

Please correct what is wrong in the gradle task.

Comment: see my answer for a simple solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

Gradle `Copy` DSL provides a method `eachFile (Closure closure)` that you can use to perform action on each file which will be copied/extracted, see [Copy DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:eachFile(groovy.lang.Closure))

In your case, you can use this method to rename (remove parent dirs from path) your file:

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
    group "testgroup"


    from( zipTree(file("test.zip")).matching { include "**/result1.jar"  } )
    into "$buildDir/dir"

    def parentDir = "web-inf/lib"
    eachFile { fcp ->
        fcp.path = fcp.path.replaceFirst("^$parentDir", '')
    }
    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```